# How can I delete comma at the end of the output in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to order a word's letters by alphabetically in Python. But there is a comma at the end of the output.(I tried ''.sort() command, it worked well but there is square brackets at the beginning and at the end of the output). The input and the output must be like this:

```
word
'd','o','r','w'
```

This is my code:

```
alphabet='AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz'
word=str(input())
for i in alphabet:
    for j in word:
        if i==j:
            print("'{}',".format(i),end='')
```

And this is my output:

```
word
'd','o','r','w',
```

Comment: Btw it’s easier to just output sorted(word), and then just print ‘,’.join(sorted(word))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python strings have a [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) function:

```
ls = ['a','b','c']
print(",".join(ls)) # prints "a,b,c"
```

Python also has what is called a ['list comprehension'](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), that you can use like so:

```
alphabet='AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz'
word=str(input())
matches = [l for l in word if l in alphabet]
print(",".join(sorted(matches)))
```

All the list comprehension does is put `l` in the list `if` it is in `alphabet`. All the candidate `l`s are taken from the `word` variable.

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) is a function that will do a simple sort (though more complex sorts are possible).

Finally; here are a few other fun options that all result in `"a,b,c,d"`:

```
"a,b,c,d,"[:-1] . # list-slice
"a,b,c,d,".strip(",") . # String strip
```

Answer (score 2):

you store it in an array and then print it at the end

```
alphabet='AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz'
word=str(input())
matches = []
for i in alphabet:
    for j in word:
        if i==j:
            matches.append("'{i}',".format(i=i))
#now that matches has all our matches
print(",".join(arrayX) # join it
```

or as others have mentioned

```
print(",".join(sorted(word)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the string.join() function.

```
alphabet='AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz'
','.join(alphabet)
```

There's really no need to anything to make the string into a list, join will iterate over it quite happily.  Tried on python 2.7 and 3.6

Answer (score -2):

## Doing it your self

The trick is in the algorithm you use.

You want to add a comma and a space, after each field, except the last. But it is hard to know which is the last, until it is too late.

It would be much easier if you could make the first field the special case, as this is mach easier to predict.

Therefore transform the algorithm to: Add a comma and a space, before each field, except the first. This produces the same output, but is a much simpler algorithm.

## Use a library

Using a library is always preferable (unless doing it just for the practice).
python has the join method. See other answers.